# shouldComponentUpdate() is causing a white screen before the screen loads

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-lifecycle

Before I started using `shouldComponentUpdate`, I used `this.forceUpdate()` and that did not work at all. So I looked into `shouldComponentUpdate` and found out it can rerender a state if it was changed. In my case I need to update my numbers and animations when the state has changed. Here is my code:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  return nextState.user_image != this.state.user_image
}
```

**The problem with this is that, when I use it, the whole screen goes white. Before the page even loads in.**

`user_image` contains a set of data from the mysql database and I have a column called `points`.

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      if (!prevState.dataSource) {

           fetch(`https://www.example.com/React/profile.php${this.state.log}` , {
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           }

          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                user_image:  responseJson[0].user_images.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0), unprogress: new Animated.Value(1) }))
                },function() {


                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              //console.error(error);
            });
    }

}
```

The reason why I have `componentDidUpdate` the way it is now is because `this.state.log` needs to be rerendered once in order to have something in it. BUT, using this method does not let the numbers of `user_image` and animations update one I click the animation. **Note: If I were to use `componentDidUpdate` without parameters, 2 things happen. 1) The performance of the app decreases by a lot, because it keeps rerendering 2) When I go to the animation, it actually does update the numbers and animation. (Which is what I am looking for!)**

Here are the animations:

```
    /* Shows the starting point of the animation and is ready to use */
    anim_star = (item) => {
            //console.log(item.id);
            Animated.timing(item.progress, {
              toValue: 1,
              duration: 2000,
              easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();
    fetch(`https://www.example.com/React/star.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      post_id : item.id,

    })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {


        }).catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });

  }

  /* Shows a finished animation and is ready to restart it */
  anim_unstar = (item) => {
            //console.log(item.id);
            Animated.timing(item.unprogress, {
              toValue: 1,
              duration: 2000,
              easing: Easing.linear,
    }).reset();
    fetch(`https://www.example.co/React/unstar.php`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      post_id : item.id,

    })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

        }).catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });

  }
```

And Lastly, here is the rest of the code:

```
<-- Animations need to change once the state has changed -->
    {this.state.id.includes(item.id)  ?
  <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.anim_unstar(item)}>
           <Animation
           progress={item.unprogress}
           source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
           />
           </TouchableOpacity>
         :
         <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => this.anim_star(item)}>
          <Animation
          progress={item.progress}
          source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}
          />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        }


         <Text>{item.points}</Text> <-- This needs to update when state is changed
```

How can I get these to update?

Comment: `dataSource` - where is from/for/changed? Fetches invoked form event/handlers doesn't end with state change (response>setState) then no rerender.

Comment: @xadm dataSource is just data that I don't even use.

Comment: then why is used as condition? Is this a component common for items selected from list (changed props) or each element has it's own?

Comment: @xadm I use it to prevent the componentDidUpdate from rerending again and again...I don't understand the second question,but that is the only use for dataSource. user_image is for everything else like items from JSON array

Comment: in fact it was question why not fetch from `componentDidMount` - fired only once in lifecycle.

Comment: @xadm Because I learned that `this.state` is asynchronous and will not be set until the page rerenders. With DidUpdate, it will update `this.state`

Comment: It's not true. It fetches when sth (state, props) changed -thats why I asked it's needed to react on changes (select other user, new props). Move initial fetch to cDM, no conditions required. Render <Loading /> when state.user_image is undefined. Arriving data will change state and render data. Later un-/star fetches should change state forcing rerender. This can broke animations but is required to update rendered view (numbers). Call setState from animation callback instead?

Comment: @xadm I mean it would be great if I can somehow play the animation until it finishes then call the fetch

Comment: It would but it's good to have sth working first.